# Compute div style only when it completes rendering an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my script I am loading an image from an array into a div, then I calculate some style elements to be tuned.
The problem is that this works only if I use a timeout function before calculating the styles, like this:

```
  $('#forecastImg').attr('src',get_ImageItemLocation(imageArray[0]));

  setTimeout(function(){ 
       var himg= $("#forecastImg").height();
       var hest = $("#esterno").height();
       var margin= ((hest-himg)/2)-$(".header").height()-$(".forecastdate").height();
       if (margin>0){
         $("#forecastImg").css('margin-top',(margin+'px'));
      }
  },240);
```

How can I get rid of the timeout and be sure that the `height()` value is correct?
If I remove the timeout, I alwyas get a `height()=0` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem here is that the image is not loaded when you're trying do calculate the margin, that's why `$('#forecastImg').height()` is not returning the expected height when you try to make the calculations right away *(in your case, you're doing a wait for the loading with a* `setTimeout`*)*

However, you can use `$().load` method instead of a unreliable `setTimeout` to consistently run your calculations after the loading of the image. To do that, you must **first** bind the `.load` callback method with those calculations **and only then** change the `src` value of it, otherwise the image might load immediately without calling our `.load` callback:

```js
  $('#forecastImg')
      .one('load', function () { 
           var himg = $("#forecastImg").height(),
               hest = $("#esterno").height(),
               margin = ((hest-himg) / 2) - $(".header").height() - $(".forecastdate").height();

           if (margin > 0) {
               $("#forecastImg").css('margin-top',(margin+'px'));
           }
      })
      .attr('src', get_ImageItemLocation(imageArray[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the image has loaded, so the timeout is correct, but if you would like to use a different solution, you can use `load` event instead:

```
$("#forecastImg").one("load", function() {
       var himg= $(this).height();
       var hest = $("#esterno").height();
       var margin= ((hest-himg)/2)-$(".header").height()-$(".forecastdate").height();
       if (margin>0){
         $("#forecastImg").css('margin-top',(margin+'px'));
      }
});
```

Comment: Just wondering, if you say the timeout is correct. For me it always feels wrong if I can't handle what I want to do with a timeout greater than 0

Comment: The problem is that `DOM` spend some time to have the elements available and rendered. Sometimes we need to wait some element to be ready or updated. In your scenario, the event is the load of the image, then you can use a specif event handler, that is better than timeout, but sometimes there isn't a event handler, and you can use the timeout as a workaround. Anyway,you don't know the exact time you must wait, so timeout is not a "good" solution.

Answer (score 1):

try the load event of JQuery

```
$('#forecastImg').load(function() {
   var himg = $("#forecastImg").height();
   var hest = $("#esterno").height();
   var margin = ((hest-himg)/2)-$(".header").height()-$(".forecastdate").height();
    if (margin > 0) {
        $("#forecastImg").css('margin-top',(margin+'px'));
    }
});
```